# I want my reference in the same ruler level

Tags: bibliographies

```
% importing reference file
\renewcommand\bibname{References} % Not sure why we need it here again
% \bibliographystyle{./IEEEtran}
% \bibliography{./IEEEfull,./reference}

\bibheader
% \renewcommand{\section}[2]{}%
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}% for other classes
\bibliographystyle{./IEEEtran}
\bibliography{./IEEEfull,./reference}}
\bioheader
\biography
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

What should I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` also include (the file with) the references.

Comment: His not normal behaviour so as Albert mentions, we need code. Also you probably should learn to use the `\url` command for typesetting those urls

Comment: The 17 in the red box at the top makes me think that Overleaf is trying to tell you that you have 17 errors/warnings in your document. Chances are one of those errors or warnings is responsible for the undesired behaviour. Check the messages and try to fix the errors. (See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7898/35864) Like daleif's, my money would be on the URL in the Davenport entry, the `_` in the URL is throwing you into math mode, which could be a problem here. Wrap your URLs in the `\url{...}` macro of the `hyperref`/`url` package.

Comment: I'm already edit this post, I'm apologize and thank you @moewe

Comment: That's better, thank you. Unfortunately this is still not enough code to let us figure out what exactly is wrong. My money is still on your URLs, but we would have to see your `.bib` file for that as well. Did you have a look at the seventeen (!) error messages you got? You should fix each of them. A document with errors will most likely not compile as intended.

Comment: I'm already fix the red box as much as I can do and it is still left yellow box, is that already okay? @moewe

Comment: I don't know, really. Ideally one should strive to obtain a document without error messages or warnings. But sometimes certain warning messages are unavoidable or have to be accepted. It depends on your situation and the warnings you get. Not having seen them I can't really comment.

Comment: you should provide a small example document and the image of the output _from that document_ posting an image of a document that we can not reproduce makes it hard to help but of the code you posted why `\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}` ? that is very odd re-definition, and will break many documents, particularly if they use `\chapter*`

Comment: you have an `_` in the URL near the end of the  arrow and it will have generated an error about `_` and missing `$`. As you can see in the output it does a subscript then the rest of that line is in math italic.  After _any_ error you should not look at the pdf at all except for debugging, TeX makes no attempt to make sensible typeset output after an error, it just recovers enough to syntax-check the rest of the document